# Add a dynamic div with JavaScript and then register in the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to register some data in a database but I want to create the input fields dynamically with JavaScript or something. I can't register the data in the database, can it depend on my JavaScript code? How do I create the fields dynamically right?

My JavaScript looks like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x <= max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append('<div id="loopdiv"><h2>Dilemma</h2> Video länk: <br><textarea type="text" rows="1" cols="40" name="videolank"></textarea><div>1.<input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></div><div>2.<input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></div><div>3.<input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></div><div>4.<input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></div><br><br></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

And my HTML is:

```html
<form action="dilemma.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!--Lägg till en bild:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Ladda upp" name="submit">
 -->
 <br><br>
 <div id="loopdiv">
 
 <h2 id="h2">Dilemma</h2> 
 Video länk: <br>
 <textarea type="text" rows="1" cols="40" name="videolank"></textarea>
 <div>1.<input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></div>
 <div>2.<input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></div>
 <div>3.<input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></div>
 <div>4.<input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></div>
 <br><br></div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <div>

  </div>
</div>
<button class="add_field_button">Lägg till fler svar</button>
</form>
```

Is there a way to add `<div id="loopdiv">` dynamically more correctly? So I can get an ID when I want to register to the database because I can't do that right now.

Comment: How do you register in the db? what values are you passing?

Comment: @Pete i'm not showing that here. I guess that the problem is with making the div. Is there a "right" way to make the div or am i on the right way?

Comment: I will state that there is no "right" way to create a div, however, [the writte function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) would be your best bet.

Comment: @HomamZraki.no issue seems the way you are appending the loopdiv. But in case you want to access the div or any element inside it.. try once with `$(document).on('click','#loopdiv',function(e) {});`, in case it doesn't let me know, will see

Comment: All I'm getting at is that when you add your div you are going to get a massive array of mytexts - up to 4 per videolank - which you may also want to add `[]` onto.  Also don't use ids unless you make them unique each time you add one.

Answer (score 2):

I've made my own example but you can match yours.

You can get your inputs like this:

```
var formElement = document.getElementById("PrForm");//form id
var formData = new FormData(formElement);//get form data
```

Send form data to the server with ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: $(formElement).attr('action'),
        type: $(formElement).attr('method'),
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData,//form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            loading.html('<center><div ><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div></center>').show();
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //returned data from server
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert(jqXHR+ textStatus+ errorThrown);
            jContent.html( "<p>Something went wrong</p>"+"-"+textStatus+"-"+errorThrown );

        },
        complete: function(){

        }
    });
```

The main idea is this, so not to loop on every input of your form.